# Use Asynctask as a private class or with broadcast receiver?

Tags: android, inheritance, android-asynctask, broadcastreceiver, inner-classes

I'm trying to make an application that uses Asynctask. Particularly, I want to make different http petitions with different JSON in different activities without the activity being frozen while the communication is done.

At first I thought to use asynctask as a private inner class in those activities, but I saw that they share a lot of code. So I thought to make a single class and play with broadcast receivers as I need to monitorize when I receive the result of the http petition, and isn't good to interfere with activity directly in the onPostExecute while in a different class.

What I want to know is, what is more efficient and better practice. Make a class that has the shared code and extends asynctask, then doing inner classes for each activity that extends that one or make a single asynctask that sends broadcast and receive them with each activity when needed.

Excuse my poor english, if needed I'll try to specify more clearly.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

### Background

> What I want to know is, what is more efficient and better practice. Make a class that has the shared code and extends asynctask, then doing inner classes for each activity that extends that one or make a single asynctask that sends broadcast and receive them with each activity when needed.

I'm unclear as to why these are your only two options. Create a single `AsyncTask`, such as `JsonPetitionTask`, then push a new `JsonPetitionTask.Data` object. This object would contain your URL, your JSON, and any other data you need.

### Setting up the AsyncTask

Something like this:

```
public class JsonPetitionTask extends AsyncTask<JsonPetitionTask.Data, Integer, Boolean> {
    protected Boolean doInBackground(JsonPetitionTask.Data... args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            JsonPetitionTask.Data data = args[i];
            // Send your JSON; check for errors, and return false if needed.
            if (isCancelled()) break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        // Show progress?
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        // result is your success true/false.
    }

    public static class Data {
        public String jsonContent;
        public String petitionUrl;

        public Data(String content, String url) {
            jsonContent = content;
            petitionUrl = url;
        }
    }
}
```

### Calling the JsonPetitionTask

Then you can call it like so:

```
JsonPetitionTask.Data data = new JsonPetitionTask.Data(myJSON, myURL);
new JsonPetitionTask().execute(data);
```

And voilà, you've executed your `AsyncTask` using only one class with no receivers.

### Implementing a callback

Now, if you want to register a callback (something to execute that is specific to the calling code), that's a bit trickier. <s>If this is part of what you're looking for, I'll be glad to edit this post and explain it.</s>

To add a callback, we can use the [`Runnable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runnable.html) class to execute some code after the job is done.

Firstly, we need to add a new field in the `Data` inner class:

```
public Runnable callback;
```

Next, before we call `execute()`, we need to add a new callback to our `data` object.

```
data.callback = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // Whatever code you want to run on completion.
    }
};
```

Third, in the `JsonPetitionTask` class, we need a list of things to run:

```
private ArrayList<Runnable> mRunnables = new ArrayList<Runnable>();
```

Make sure, in each iteration of the `doInBackground()` loop, that you do `mRunnables.add(data.callback);`.

Lastly, in `onPostExecute()`, we need to call this:

```
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    for (Runnable r : mRunnables)
        if (r != null) r.run();
}
```

I do realize I didn't send `result` to the `Runnable`, however I didn't feel like implementing a new `Runnable` type just to handle that. If you need this, I guess that's a bit of homework for you!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer ^^. But I didn't explain well myself. The problem is just that, I need to know when the asynctask ends and receives the answer from the http request to continue with the activity, as you say, a callback. Thats why I was saying the broadcast thing, as I don't have access to the activity from a created object independent to the activity. The same thing goes to the inner class, as I have access to the activity from here but still exists the problem if the activity changes (like when rotating the screen or when exiting the current activity)

Comment: You're welcome! Have you tried it out? Does it serve your purposes?

Comment: Sorry I didnt complete the answer yet, as im not used to this, when clicked Enter, it sent the answer right away ^^'

Comment: Whew, that was quite an edit. I've posted up some details on setting up a callback. Good luck! :)

Comment: Thanks again, I think I need some sleep now, as it's pretty late here, but when I try it i'll tell you the results ^^.

Comment: After much work and testing I have concluded that the most efficient way of handling an asynctask is using it as an inner class as it's design is meant to use it like that. This way we don't need additional ways to handle the OnPostExecute whenever the thread ends. To avoid the repeat of code its best to make an abstract class that extends asynctask and make each particular class to expand its function as needed. Thanks again Eric for your help, I have learned some things I didn't know, as I never used the runnable class till now.

Comment: Indeed you are right, but being able to handily reuse code is one of the most important skills you will find. Perhaps you would want a utils class of some kind to reference from each `AsyncTask` so they're all running similar code.

Answer (score 1):

The way I found the best is just simply create public class that extends AsyncTask and then you just override onPostExecute function in every activity you use it.

Example:

```
MyDataTask dataTask = new MyDataTask() //you can add your parameters in class constructor
        {
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Object result) //replace Object with your result type
            {
                MyActivity.this.doStuff(result); //use result in current activity
            }
        };
```

you can also create some custom functions to set private variables in datatask

```
dataTask.AddParam("user", username);
dataTask.AddParam("pass", pass);
```

and then just execute it with your args...

```
dataTask.execute(myArgs);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used Async task class as single class. And for every Webservice call i have used unique IntentFilter to Broadcast response.
Put that Broadcast receiver in every class. You have perfect solution.
Its working well.

Comment: Yup. I have used this type of class. And really its saved my time as no need to create class for every Async Task. Thanks @Ashish Vora